# Where is the [modelname]_path-method implemented?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

can somebody Tell me where this method is implemented respectively what happens behind the scenes in rail 4?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Creating a resourceful route exposes a number of helpers (generates named routes) to the controllers and views in your application.

In the case of resources :photos:

```
photos_path returns /photos
new_photo_path returns /photos/new
edit_photo_path(:id) returns /photos/:id/edit (for instance, edit_photo_path(10) returns /photos/10/edit)
photo_path(:id) returns /photos/:id (for instance, photo_path(10) returns /photos/10)
```

Each of these helpers has a corresponding _url helper (such as photos_url) which returns the same path prefixed with the current host, port and path prefix.

**ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper::Base** module is responsible for generating these helpers.
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Base.html

I suggest you to take a look at the rails guides for routing.
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Using the command *rake routes* you can see the list of all routes defined.

Answer (score 0):

The interesting bits are in the class `ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet`. When adding a named route (see [NamedRouteCollection#add](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/6b548830828e4e910de7854d21717c17303e089c/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb#L122-L125)), Rails will dynamically add a method named `"#{route}_path"` (see [NamedRouteCollection::UrlHelper#define_named_route_methods](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/6b548830828e4e910de7854d21717c17303e089c/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb#L262-L280)).

Rails internally uses [`define_method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-define_method), which lets you dynamically define methods at runtime.